# React, Local cached variable and firing onclick on render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a local variable for each component instance, something like a little cache because it is storing information that toggles something and does not need to be on the state/store. So I have attempted it like so:

Setting a default prop to keep my info in :

```
getDefaultProps: function getDefaultProps() {
    return {
        showPreviewModal: { value: false,
                            writable: true
                        }
    };
},
```

Setting a function to toggle this prop :

```
 togglePreviewModal: function togglePreviewModal() {
    this.props.showPreviewModal = !this.props.showPreviewModal;
},
```

And having that function fired by a click function

```
 <button className="btn btn-default btn-blue previewAsset" onClick={() => this.togglePreviewModal() }>
```

I thought this would work in theory, but the onclick is firing immedietly on render. I googled this issue and it seems like the best result is to change the click function to :

```
{() => { this.props.togglePreviewModal() }}
```

However this does not work either, the click function is still firing immediately.

Comment: You cannot modify `this.props` of a React component. If you need the component to store information that is not known outside of the component, you have to use state.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly mutate props like that - since props are explicitly passed down from a parent component, you'd need to change the prop at the source. Presumably, it originates from the state of a component somewhere up the hierarchy.

To do that, you'd pass down a function along with the prop that changes it at the source (using `setState()`). Here's an example:

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    togglePreviewModal: function() {
        this.setState({
            showPreviewModal: !this.state.showPreviewModal
        };
    },        

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            // Unnecessary but providing for clarity
            showPreviewModal: false
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        // This is for whatever values you were mapping over
        var childComponents = ...map(function() {
            return <ChildComponent togglePreviewModal={this.togglePreviewModal} />;
        });

        if (this.state.showPreviewModal) {
            return (<div>
                <Modal />
                {childComponents}
            </div>);
        } else {
            return (<div>
                {childComponents}
            </div>);
        }
    }
});

var ChildComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <button
            className="btn btn-default btn-blue previewAsset"
            onClick={this.props.togglePreviewModal} />;
    }
});
```

Note that I'm not invoking the function in the onClick of the `<button>`, just passing in the prop (which is a function).

Comment: So this works but only for the first component that is mapped over.

Comment: Could you edit your post to add a sample of what you're working with? What are you mapping?

Comment: So the difference is this item that is toggling show/hide the modal is used multiple times. There are results that come in and for each of those results this component is rendered once. What I meant by that first comment is, it works, but only for the first result item. The ones after that do not open the modal.

Comment: So there is one modal and multiple child components that have the ability to toggle the modal?

Comment: Just updated the code snippet to something closer to what I think you're describing. I would only render the modal once, in the parent (since only one modal can be rendered at one time anyway), and then pass the function to show or hide it to each of the child components that you're mapping over.